# 2 Possible Currents and Vdrops from same Resistor: Which Will it Be? [Beginner]

Tags: resistors, basic

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fd37Xn.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Let's say I have a power supply that supplies 5v and 3A.

If I add a 2 ohm resistor, it could do 2 different things.

Realizing that resistance = volts/amps...

either it will drop the voltage by 1 volt and give 0.5A, as 1/0.5 = 2 ohms

OR it will drop the voltage by 4 volts and give 2A, as 4/2 = 2 ohms.

Let's just assume the power rating on the resistor is high enough that we don't have to worry about it for this example.

**Question**

So which one of these two scenarios will become the reality if I have just the power source and a single 2 ohm resistor? And why? Otherwise, if you suspect there is some concept I fail to misunderstand, please explain that as well. I'm basically saying, according to ohm's law it seems both these scenarios are possible when deciding a voltage drop and current to find a resistor value. I'm trying to ask a basic question to understand resistors, not asking because of a real life application.

Comment: Do you mean there is a power supply designed to provide \$5\:\text{V}\$ and that it is already loaded with a fixed resistance that results in \$3\:\text{A}\$ and that you will now insert a \$2\:\Omega\$ resistor in series with the existing load? Or in parallel with the existing load? Or something else? What do you mean by "add," I guess. What is the existing "circuit" you are talking about?

Comment: You fail to understand that your terms are ambiguous, and that we can't see the picture in your head. Add a schematic for the circuit before you add the 2ohm resistor, and after adding it. Hit the edit button below your post, then the resistor/pencil/diode/capacitor button on the edit box toolbar to bring up a schematic editor.

Comment: Your power supply is a _constant voltage_ one, meaning you have two knowns, U and R, and one unknown, I.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the supply potential is 5V and can delivery up to 3A then a 2Ω load will draw only 2.5A (=5V/2Ω) and still see 5V.

This may continue if the load is reduced to 1.66Ω (=5V/3A) but any lower may shut down the supply.

Comment: Thanks, I realized the voltage drop across that one resistor would be 5V, leaving it at 0 at the end, a Kirchhoff law. Then I realized that I had to look at voltage drop across more than one resistor in series to learn what I was missing.